# User specific dashboard in Sharepoint

Tags: sharepoint, dynamic, web-parts, dashboard

So I'm building dashboard that consists of more sections. I'm planning to build each section as a web-part. Dashboard is going to be Site Page. Problem is I have more levels of users, and these levels have different dashboards (different sections and layout). How to make site page dynamic and user specific?

Answer (score 0):

there are two approaches you could use. I think the best one is the AudienceFilter where you could make elements available for various audiences.

Another apporach is to group users into SharePoint groups and build a GroupTrimmedControl SharePoint already offers the SPSecurityTrimmedControl which is a great starting point.

But when you're not limited to MSF (SharePoint Foundation) you should have a look at the AudienceFilter.